# How to add css in php file?

Tags: php, css

Here is my php code:

```
if($_GET['cmd']=='7') {
    reports();
    bar();
    $strXML=past7days();    
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a id="default" href="#" style="color:#000; text-decoration:none"><? echo date('M dS Y' ,strtotime($startdate)); ?> to <? echo date('M dS Y' ,strtotime($enddate)); ?></a>
```

I want to add

```
#default{
 color:#000; 
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

using php.

How i do this?

Comment: Where are your html headers created? What do functions reports() and bar() do? What do you actually do with the $strXML variable? In PHP (without a framework) you simply print out the CSS wherever you print the HTML header.

Comment: What css do you want to add where and under what circumstances. Also, your shown code snippets dont seem to have any relation to your question?

Comment: try using echo with this in it <style> YOUR CSS </style>

Comment: Would you care to tell us what those functions do and why you'd want to dynamicly add the same style ? I'm confused...

Comment: Create a file called `style.css` and `include()` it. N'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a file called css.css or whatever. put your #default styles in that file. and at top of this page add before opening the php brackets:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" media="screen">
```